# Comment-handling from the Close review queue is inconsistent

Tags: bug, review, comment-voting

Today I noticed that I can't upvote or flag comments from the Close review queue, which I think I used to be able to do.<sup>1</sup>  But one item in the queue had a "show N more comments" link, and after I clicked that I *could* vote on comments on *that* post.  (Just clicking "add comment" on a post where all comments are already displayed doesn't work, though.)  I've turned off Greasemonkey to rule out interference from user scripts; no change.  This is in Firefox 28.0 on Mac OS 10.6.

If the behavior is intentional and not considered a bug, isn't it a little peculiar that I can leave a new comment but not upvote an existing one?

<sup>1</sup> "I think" because the queues don't all behave the same way with respect to what you can do on posts.  I know I've upvoted comments from review and I use this queue frequently; I'm pretty sure I've seen that behavior here.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me; the client-side JS code that loads the extra comments also re-enables the disabled commenting form.